# Two collapsible fieldgroups. When I open one of this collapsible fieldgroups, the other closes and reverse

Tags: entities

Is a question about the [Field group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module. 
I have two field groups with the "Div" format. The two fieldgroups are collapsible. What I want to get is that when I open one of this collapsible fieldgroups, the other closes and reverse.
I asked this same question in the forum module issues, but got no answer except that would make it in this forum, which is more appropriate. I think that is a question about js or css, and I tried one and thousand tutorials, but I have not managed to find the solution…

What i have to do to get this?
Could anyone help me (please)?

Comment: Any help please!?